# Easy way to tell powershell that the number i am working with is in MB not Bytes so it can be converted to GB

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, int

I am getting a size property from a wmi class that shows the size of directory but it in MBs it is not in Bytes.  I want to convert this to GBs but powershell always assumes it is Bytes so 20gbs is actually showing as 2MBs.  Is there an easy wat to format this number before changing it to GBs so powershell knows it is MBs not Bytes?  I know i can add zeros or multiply by 1024 but i was trying to find something simple.

I have tried:

```
("{0:N1} MB" -f 20480 / 1gb)
```

But that formats it as string and doesn't work.

Comment: Do `("{0}mb" -f 2048)/1gb`.

Comment: You could also just multiply by 1mb first to convert mb to bytes - e.g. “20480 * 1mb / 1gb” gives 20...

Comment: That's very cool. But if you have a number why don't you just use it 2048*1mb/1GB For either approach you can use the Math class to round it: [Math]::Round( (2048*1MB/1gb), 2 ), you other wise won't always have a nice even number.